# How to came back to the tabhost activity when i call external browser from the content of the fragment which is existed in the Tabhost Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have one tabactivity with 4 tabs, when I click on one tab I am displaying some information regarding that tab. To display that content I am using fragment. In that fragment i have facebook button, twitter button etc. to post a link into my facebook account and twitter account.  When clicking on the facebook or twitter button, it navigates to the browser based on the corresponding link to post the information. When I click on back button to come back to my application but the application is closed already.